# Can long waiting threads throttle cpu in kubernetes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

Can multiple long waiting threads (blocked on remote rest call response, non cpu-bound) throttle CPU ?
This cpu throttle causes leads to pod restart as health check response takes time to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something blocked in a waiting syscall (select and friends, sleep(), blocking read or write) does not count as using any CPU time, the task (how Linux thinks about threads internally) won't be marked as runnable until something interrupts the wait.

Comment: thanks @coderanger for clarifying

would you take a dig at this pls too

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532078/hikaripool-connection-not-available-after-long-i-o-operation-for-concurrent-requ